# how to connect from oracle origin with streamsets

Tags: oracle, ojdbc, streamsets

i want to create an origin source from oracle. so I choos as origin oracle cdc. then I configured each parameter:

- Schema Name
- Table
- Username
- Password
- JDBC Connection String

  but when I run the process, i find into my log:

```
2017-08-22 11:07:22,447 test/testb156f588-dbd7-4e4c-8896-caf658d14d77   ERROR   Error while connecting to DB

com.streamsets.pipeline.api.StageException: JDBC_06 - Failed to initialize connection pool: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =
(ENABLE=BROKEN)
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost)(PORT = myport))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = orcl.WORLD)))
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.jdbc.JdbcUtil.createDataSourceForRead(JdbcUtil.java:638)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.origin.jdbc.cdc.oracle.OracleCDCSource.init(OracleCDCSource.java:643)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.api.base.BaseStage.init(BaseStage.java:52)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.configurablestage.DStage.init(DStage.java:40)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StageRuntime.init(StageRuntime.java:156)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StagePipe.init(StagePipe.java:105)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StagePipe.init(StagePipe.java:53)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.Pipeline.initPipe(Pipeline.java:299)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.Pipeline.init(Pipeline.java:214)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.common.ProductionPipeline.run(ProductionPipeline.java:96)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.common.ProductionPipelineRunnable.run(ProductionPipelineRunnable.java:79)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.standalone.StandaloneRunner.start(StandaloneRunner.java:646)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.common.AsyncRunner.lambda$start$3(AsyncRunner.java:143)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.call(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:233)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =
(ENABLE=BROKEN)
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost)(PORT = myport))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = orcl.WORLD)))
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:88)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolElf.initializeDataSource(PoolElf.java:157)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:113)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:73)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.jdbc.JdbcUtil.createDataSourceForRead(JdbcUtil.java:630)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:81)
    ... 23 more
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the ojdbc jar under the repository

```
/opt/streamsets-extra/streamsets-datacollector-jdbc-lib/lib
```

Comment: since i m running on docker , how would it be cfg ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that it's missing to set environment variable **STREAMSETS_LIBRARIES_EXTRA_DIR** which's a part of installing external library installation process.

There are three types of installation depending on initialization style of Data Collector :

- ***Manually*** start
- Using ***SysV Init*** ( supported by *CentOS 6, Oracle Linux 6, Red Hat
  Enterprise Linux 6* or *Ubuntu 14.04 LTS* )
- Using ***Systemd Init*** ( supported by *CentOS 7, Oracle Linux 7, Red Hat
  Enterprise Linux 7* or *Ubuntu 16.04 LTS* )

If you're installing **SDC**

- being started ***manually***, then variable **STREAMSETS_LIBRARIES_EXTRA_DIR** is expected to be set from the command line by

  ```
  export STREAMSETS_LIBRARIES_EXTRA_DIR="/opt/streamsets-data-collector/streamsets-data-collector-3.15.0/streamsets-libs-extras/"
  ```
- starting as a ***service***, then this parameter already would already exist
  within the ***$SDC_DIST/libexec/_sdc*** file as

  ```
  STREAMSETS_LIBRARIES_EXTRA_DIR="${STREAMSETS_LIBRARIES_EXTRA_DIR:=${SDC_DIST}/streamsets-libs-extras}"
  ```

where ***$SDC_DIST*** variable is the extraction directory for SDC installation file(*tarball* or *RPM*).

and the same path should be added to the file ***$SDC_CONF/sdc-security.policy*** such as

```
grant codebase "file:///opt/streamsets-data-collector/streamsets-data-collector-3.15.0/streamsets-libs-extras/-" {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

where ***$SDC_CONF*** variable is typically defined by the path ***/etc/sdc***

Now, we're ready to log in Data Collector Console in order to add **JDBC External library** following these steps :

1. In Data Collector, in the top right toolbar, click the **Package
   Manager** icon:
   [image]
2. In the navigation panel, click **External Libraries** :

[image]

Data Collector lists any currently installed external libraries.

3. Immediately under the top right toolbar, click the **Install
   External Libraries** icon:

[image]

4. In the **Install External Libraries** dialog box, select the stage
   library **JDBC** from the file system (assuming you were already registered and downloaded **streamsets-datacollector-jdbc-lib**);

[image]

and the choose the **.jar** file such as **ojdbc8.jar** which can be downloaded from [JDBC and UCP Downloads page](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html) ( in my case I've chosen the link named *Oracle Database 12c Release 2 (12.2.0.1) drivers* due to my remote DB version ).

5. As the last step, Don't forget to click **Cancel** in the **Install External Libraries** window, and then run the following command :

   ```
   service sdc restart ( for SysV Init)
   ```

   or

   ```
   systemctl restart sdc ( for Systemd Init )
   ```

( *You can click **Restart Data Collector** in the **Install External Libraries** window provided that you started the Data Collector manually from the command line.* )

Answer (score 0):

Under the **Legacy** configuration tab try specifying the **JDBC Driver Class name** as **oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver**